# Big O notation sum rule

Tags: asymptotics, proof-writing

I understand that when adding functions, the behavior is dominated by the highest power. But what I am having trouble is understanding the proof. Could anyone help me step by step in explaining the proof behind $T_1(n) + T_2(n) = O(max (f(n), g(n)))$ ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean $f(n)+g(n) = O(\max(f(n), g(n)))$?

Comment: I guess but doesn't it not matter? If T(n) is in O(f(n)) it doesnt necessarily have to mean that O(f(n)) is the same function does it?

Comment: Well, you didn't state any relation between $T_1$ and $T_2$ on the one hand, and $f$ and $g$ on the other hand, and without that there's no way to say anything about them. Did you mean to say that $T_1(n) = O(f(n))$ and that $T_2(n) = O(g(n))$?

Comment: Yes sorry I guess I shouldve specified. I was assuming formal definition of Big O for both T(n) and T2(n)

Answer (score 20):

Given $T_1(n)=O(f(n))$ and $T_2(n)=O(g(n))$, we are to prove $$T_1(n)+T_2(n)=O(\max(f(n),g(n))\tag0$$

- Write down exactly what the first assumption says: there exists a constant $C_1$ and an index $N_1$ such that 
  $$|T_1(n)| \le C_1f(n)\quad \text{when } n\ge N_1 \tag1$$
- Write down exactly what the second assumption says: there exists a constant $C_2$ and an index $N_2$ such that 
  $$|T_2(n)| \le C_2g(n)\quad \text{when } n\ge N_2 \tag2$$
- Prepare to combine (1) and (2) by introducing $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ and $C=\max(C_1,C_2)$.
- Add (1) and (2): 
  $$
  |T_1(n)|+|T_2(n)|\le  C_1f(n)+C_2g(n) \le C(f(n)+g(n))\quad \text{when } n\ge N \tag3
  $$
- Check that for any two real numbers $a,b$ we have $$a+b\le 2\max(a,b)\tag4$$
- Use (4) in (3) to obtain 
  $$
  |T_1(n)|+|T_2(n)|\le 2C\max(f(n),g(n))\quad \text{when } n\ge N \tag5
  $$
- Conclude that (0) holds.

Comment: Canonical job. +1.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum) asserts that $f_1\in\mathcal O(g_1)$ and $f_2\in\mathcal O(g_2)$ imply $f_1+f_2\in\mathcal O(g_1+g_2)$ (without proof). I can easily see why $f_1+f_2\in\mathcal O(\max\{g_1,g_2\})$, but how can one reconcile the result in the Wiki article with the result proved here?

Comment: @user170231, $|f_1(n) + f_2(n)| \leq |f_1(n)| + |f_2(n)|$ and the rest follows exactly as done in line (3), which is precisely the definition of $f_1+f_2 \in \mathcal{O}(g_1+g_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering non-negative functions we can say more, that sets $O(f)+O(g),O(f+g),O(\max(f,g))$ are same i.e. equality we can understand **as equality between sets**, not only as "$\subset$", i.e. one way direction. So we have
$$O(f)+O(g)=O(f+g)=O(\max(f,g))$$
as sets.

For proof, for example, last is enough to use $f+g\leqslant 2\cdot \max(f,g)\leqslant 2\cdot (f+g)$