# Big-O Analysis: Max Bounded by the Sum

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

I have been asked to show that:

$$
\mathcal{O}(Max\{ f(n), g(n) \}) = \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n))
$$

I have seen [explanations of similar problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324200/big-o-notation-sum-rule), but this is the first time I have encountered the equals ($=$) sign being used to describe a relationship between two complexity classes (e.g.—$ \mathcal{O}(f) = \mathcal{O}(g) $).

Here is my attempt at the problem:

If $f(n) > 0$ and $g(n) > 0$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$, then

$f(n) < f(n) + g(n)$, and
    $g(n) < f(n) + g(n)$.

Therefore, by definition, $f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n))$ and $g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n))$. Given that $Max\{f(n), g(n)\}$ must be either $f(n)$ or $g(n)$, it follows then that:

$$Max\{f(n), g(n)\} \in \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n)).$$

However, I am not sure whether showing this is the same as showing:
$$
\mathcal{O}(Max\{ f(n), g(n) \}) = \mathcal{O}(f(n) + g(n)).
$$

For example, if I know that $n^2+1 \in \mathcal{O}(n^2)$, may I then write that $\mathcal{O}(n^2+1)$ *equals* $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$? I understand that such a relationship is not necessarily symmetric (as might be suggested by the '$=$' symbol); would this statement simply imply that $\mathcal{O}(n^2+1) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(n^2)$?

I'd greatly appreciate any clarification and feedback on my approach. I may have completely missed the mark here.

Comment: The use of an equals sign is generally considered an abuse of notation, it's really a one way equality. So it's better to use $\in$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f(n) + g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(\text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\})$, note that $f(n) \le \text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\}$ and $g(n) \le \text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\}$. So, what do you know about $f(n)+g(n)$?

After you've shown $\text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\} \in \mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$ and $f(n)+g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(\text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\})$, then you know that $\mathcal{O}(\text{Max}\{f(n),g(n)\}) = \mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response!