# Little $o$ and big $O$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

1. The sum of a little $o$ and a big $O$ is given by the little $o$?
2. The sum of two big $O$ is a little $o$?

In studying I have encountered an implication that seems to imply these facts but I am not sure. If it is, someone can explain me why this holds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simplify $f(x)=O(g(x))+O(h(x))$.

$$f(x)=O(\max\{g,h\}).$$
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324200/big-o-notation-sum-rule/450718) is a proof from MSE.

> Simplify $f(x)=o(g(x)+O(h(x)).$

Note that $o(f)\subseteq{O}(f)$. That means that if something is $o(f)$, it's also $O(f)$. (The reverse does not always hold). So
$$f(x)=o(g(x))+O(h(x))=O(g(x))+O(h(x))=O(\max\{g,h\}).$$

**Edit:**
The statement $O(h^2)+O(h^2)=o(h)$ is incorrect:
Note that
$$O(h^2)+O(h^2)=O(\max\{h^2,h^2\})=O(h^2).$$

In other words you are saying that $O(h^2)=o(h)$. Choose $h(x)=x$ to show an counterexample.

Observe that $x^{1+1/2}=O(x^2)$. So that would mean by $O(x^2)=o(x)$ that
$$x^{1+1/2}=o(x),$$
which is absolutely wrong.

A note: As @user6725906 correctly pointed out in the comments, it depends on the limit. But if you write expressions like $\sim,o,O,\Omega,$ etc. without further information, this is (always) understood as $x\to\infty$. If you want to specify the limit (for example for $a$) you should write something like
$$f(x)=o(g(x)),\qquad (x\to a).$$

Comment: Ok thanks! But how it is possible that I have read $O(h^2)+O(h^2)=o(h)$?

Comment: @Nik First of all you should note that what I wrote holds for all functions $f,g,h$. Sometimes one can find better boundaries for $f$, but you have to look at the properties of these functions individually.

Comment: Maybe my doubt is not clear: for what you have wirtten down in the answer I should have $O(h^2)+O(h^2)=O(h^2)$ this is as to say $o(h)$, why? $o(h)=O(h^2)$?

Comment: @Nik I am editing my answer. Wait 3 minutes.

Comment: @Nik That depends on the limit of $h$. If $f(h),g(h)$ are $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ as $h\to 0$, then $\frac{f(h)+g(h)}{h^2}$ is bounded near 0. In particular $h\frac{f(h)+g(h)}{h^2}=\frac{f(h)+g(h)}{h}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, so $f(h),g(h)$ are in fact $o(h)$. But if $h\to \infty$ this formula doesn't hold.

Comment: @vitamind Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user6725906 Thanks as matter of fact I am referring to the limit as $h\rightarrow 0$!

Comment: @vitamind sorry my fail! I have not specified that I am referring to the limit of $h$ that goes to $0$

Comment: @Nik Okay. Question: Do you mean by $h$ a function of $x$ (where $x\to0$) or is $h$ the variable itself?

Comment: @vitamind $h$ as function of $x$

Comment: @Nik This does not seem true either, at least not for general cases. If a function is little o it is also big O. So you are implying that $O(h(x)^2)=O(h(x))$ for $x\to0$, holds for ALL functions $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, $O(f)$ and $o(f)$ are sets of functions, and we can add them in the sense$$S+T:=\{g+h|g\in S,\,h\in T\},$$where $g+h$ is a pointwise addition of functions $g,\,h$. With that out of the way, $o(g)+O(h)$ is $O(h)$ if $g\in O(h)$ or $o(g)$ if $h\in o(g)$. In some cases, neither of these conditions hold. For a small-$x$ convention (so $x^2\in o(x)\subset O(x),\,o(x^2)\subset O(x^2)\subset o(x)$) example, $g(x):=x,\,h(x):=\sin\tfrac1x$ would be such a tricky case. Meanwhile, as @vitamin.d noted, $O(g)+O(h)=O(\max\{g,\,h\})$ (in the sense of a pointwise maximum).